# Share multiple images on Instagram in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode6, instagram

I am working on an application in which we need to share multiple image at a time on instagram . i have searched a lot but could not find any solution. I am using the code for sharing single image on Instagram :

```
 NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image.igo",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject]];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:nil];
    UIImage *sharingImg = (UIImage *)[self.watermarkedImagesArr objectAtIndex:0];
    sharingImg =[self imageWithImage:sharingImg scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(sharingImg.size.width/4, sharingImg.size.height/4)];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(sharingImg) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
 NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imagePath];

_docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:instagramURL];
_docController.delegate = self;
_docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
self.docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Photo watermark app" forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
[self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code can help you

```
NSArray* arryOfImgs = @[image1, image2, image3]; 
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:arryOfImgs
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Comment: do you have any example of share multiple photos in instragram?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about DocumentInteractionController, but using UIActivityViewController you can open multiple images. For Instagram share you need to implement Custom activity which opens instgram app to share!

Comment: UIActivityViewController doesn't not allow to open instagram app.

Comment: Yea! For that u must use custom UIActivity